# Combining multiple rows per observation into one in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have the following problem: I have a data frame where the values of different variables of one observation are spread over multiple rows, like this:

| Id | Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.2 | NA |
| A | NA | 0.3 |
| B | 0.4 | NA |
| B | NA | 0.5 |

I tried to convert it in a way, that each observation is in one row:

|  | Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.2 | 0.3 |
| B | 0.4 | 0.5 |

But I could´nt come up with a solution...
I would very much appreciate it if someone has some ideas on how to solve that.

Comment: One way among others: `df %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~first(na.omit(.))))`

Comment: Yes this answers my question, thank you very much!

Comment: Don't agree with closing this question, the supposed duplicate requests a tidyverse solution whereas there is a much simpler base solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure each ID only has one non-missing value per element:

```
> aggregate( .~Id , data=dat, max, na.rm=TRUE, na.action = NULL)

  Id Var1 Var2
1  A  0.2  0.3
2  B  0.4  0.5
```

Data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="Id  Var1    Var2
A   0.2     NA
A   NA  0.3
B   0.4     NA
B   NA  0.5", header=TRUE)
```